# How do I unit test django urls?

Tags: django, unit-testing, tdd, django-urls

I have achieved 100% test coverage in my application everywhere except my `urls.py`. Do you have any recommendations for how I could write *meaningful* unit tests for my URLs?

FWIW This question has arisen as I am experimenting with Test-Driven Development and want failing tests before I write code to fix them.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

One way would be to [`reverse`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse) URL names and validate

Example

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^archive/(\d{4})/$', archive, name="archive"),
    url(r'^archive-summary/(\d{4})/$', archive, name="archive-summary"),
]
```

Now, in the test

```
from django.urls import reverse

url = reverse('archive', args=[1988])
assertEqual(url, '/archive/1988/')

url = reverse('archive-summary', args=[1988])
assertEqual(url, '/archive-summary/1988/')
```

You are probably testing the views anyways.

Now, to test that the URL connect to the right view, you could use [`resolve`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/urlresolvers/#resolve)

```
from django.urls import resolve

resolver = resolve('/summary/')
assertEqual(resolver.view_name, 'summary')
```

Now in the variable `resolver` ([`ResolverMatch`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/urlresolvers/#django.urls.ResolverMatch) class instance), you have the following options

```
 'app_name',
 'app_names',
 'args',
 'func',
 'kwargs',
 'namespace',
 'namespaces',
 'url_name',
 'view_name'
```

Comment: FYI my colleagues have taken this concept and made an ["assert"](https://github.com/incuna/incuna-test-utils/blob/master/incuna_test_utils/testcases/urls.py#L8) for it in [our new unittest testing utils library](https://github.com/incuna/incuna-test-utils).

Comment: I'm using: `assertEqual(resolver.func.func_name, 'archive')` to test that the resolver lands on the correct view. As far as I understand `resolver.view_name` is actually the name of the url rule, not the view.

Comment: Do you advocate using `reverse(...)` for urls in Django tests in general (i.e., for views), or just in this case to specifically unit test urls?  I see it used a lot in view testing, but it feels like an anti-pattern.

Comment: What makes you think it is an antipattern @tedmiston ?

Comment: Because I can change 1 character in the url to break my API, but all tests will still pass.  I suppose we could unit test each route with a simple assert equals... I just haven't seen that done before.

Comment: How do you test APPEND_SLASH using get_resolver()? It seems the resolver will throw a 404 even if APPEND_SLASH is True and the configured urls.py entry has a slash in it, but what you are trying to resolve does not. Is that on purpose?

Answer (score 4):

Just complementing the answer from @karthikr (on the basis of his)

-> you may assert that the view in charge of resolve is the one you'd expect using `resolver.func.cls`

*example*

```py
from unittest import TestCase
from django.urls import resolve

from foo.api.v1.views import FooView


class TestUrls(TestCase):
    def test_resolution_for_foo(self):
        resolver = resolve('/api/v1/foo')
        self.assertEqual(resolver.func.cls, FooView)
```

Comment: Then what is `view_name`?

Comment: @AlanH to be honest I wondn't assert over the name

Comment: Although it might feel fragile, asserting on name is a documented method. Just worth thinking on. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/testing/tools/

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for beeing a miner but I found this place as a first under key words "django url testing".

I fairly agree with my predecessors but I am also sure there is a better way to test your URLs. The main reason why we should not use "**resolver = resolve('url/path')**" is that the paths are of some kind fluent when the view's names are more fixed.

Well in simple words, this is better:

```
class TestUrls(TestCase):

    def test_foo_url_resolves(self):
        url = reverse('bar:foo')
        self.assertEqual(resolve(url).func.view_class, FooBarView)
```

*'bar:foo' - bar is a namespace and foo is a view name*

than this

```
class TestUrls(TestCase):
    def test_resolution_for_foo(self):
        resolver = resolve('/api/v1/foo')
        self.assertEqual(resolver.func.cls, FooView)
```

Comment: So are you saying that testing the URL is as you expect is unnecessary ? Care to elaborate on that ?